# Collecting variables from Subscript

Tags: variable-definitions, data-acquisition

I have followings set:

```
t = Transpose[{x[#] & /@ Range[20], RandomInteger[15, 20]}];
Subscript[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ t
```

The code is just to build my set.So my set of variables is something like:

```
{Subscript[x[1], 7], Subscript[x[2], 15], Subscript[
x[3], 3], Subscript[x[4], 4], Subscript[x[5], 0], Subscript[
x[6], 1], Subscript[x[7], 15], Subscript[x[8], 1], Subscript[
x[9], 0], Subscript[x[10], 2], Subscript[x[11], 0], Subscript[
x[12], 10], Subscript[x[13], 12], Subscript[x[14], 11], Subscript[
x[15], 9], Subscript[x[16], 8], Subscript[x[17], 11], Subscript[
x[18], 4], Subscript[x[19], 0], Subscript[x[20], 1]}
```

How can I pick and add up all variables which has the same subscripts from my set.For example like:

```
Subscript[x[14], 11]+Subscript[x[17], 11]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Gather like this:

```
t = Transpose[{x[#] & /@ Range[20], RandomInteger[15, 20]}];
d = Subscript[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ t;
Total /@ Gather[d, #1[[2]] == #2[[2]] &]
```